# Format and style a xml resource + assign to textview

Tags: android, xml, string, resources, textview

I'd like to format a string from resource and do some formatting on it, too!

xml resource:

```
<string name="itemFormatString">%1$s\n\n<i>%2$s</i></string>
```

I've tried several combination but i didnt get it how to solve that directly.
I do not want to create any Spannable objects within code, which should not be neccessary imo.
(I made it working already using a Spannable, because i dont get how to both format a resource string but still keep the "style" character).

The ending up string gets assigned to a textview.

greetings,
michael

Comment: What is the output you need after formatting the string?

Answer (score 0):

Just add whatever styles you want to the TextView in your xml.
For instance, if you wanted to make your String bold (as an easy example) just do:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And then in your activity just set your string to the formatted textView:

```
findViewById(R.id.textView).setText(itemFormatString);
```